# jQuery gallery error using asp.net repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, photo-gallery

I am using asp.net repeater to display the photos and am following http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html
However, I am getting the following javascript error:

```
  'jQuery' is undefined  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 10 character 2
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 505 character 5
  'this.currentImage.index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 508 character 6
  'this.currentImage.index' is null or not an object  jquery.galleriffic.js, line 286 character 5
```

Below is the code for the aspx page:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="galleriffic.aspx.vb" Inherits="galleriffic" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>



        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" type="text/css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/galleriffic-5.css" type="text/css" />


        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/white.css" type="text/css" /> -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/black.css" type="text/css" />


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.history.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>

        <!-- We only want the thunbnails to display when javascript is disabled -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<style>.noscript { display: none; }</style>');

            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
                $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

                // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
                // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
                var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
                $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li, div.navigation a.pageLink').opacityrollover({
                    mouseOutOpacity: onMouseOutOpacity,
                    mouseOverOpacity: 1.0,
                    fadeSpeed: 'fast',
                    exemptionSelector: '.selected'
                });

                // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
                var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                    delay: 2500,
                    numThumbs: 10,
                    preloadAhead: 10,
                    enableTopPager: false,
                    enableBottomPager: false,
                    imageContainerSel: '#slideshow',
                    controlsContainerSel: '#controls',
                    captionContainerSel: '#caption',
                    loadingContainerSel: '#loading',
                    renderSSControls: true,
                    renderNavControls: true,
                    playLinkText: 'Play Slideshow',
                    pauseLinkText: 'Pause Slideshow',
                    prevLinkText: '&lsaquo; Previous Photo',
                    nextLinkText: 'Next Photo &rsaquo;',
                    nextPageLinkText: 'Next &rsaquo;',
                    prevPageLinkText: '&lsaquo; Prev',
                    enableHistory: true,
                    autoStart: false,
                    syncTransitions: true,
                    defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
                    onSlideChange: function (prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                        // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                        this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
                            .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
                            .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);

                        // Update the photo index display
                        this.$captionContainer.find('div.photo-index')
                            .html('Photo ' + (nextIndex + 1) + ' of ' + this.data.length);
                    },
                    onPageTransitionOut: function (callback) {
                        this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
                    },
                    onPageTransitionIn: function () {
                        var prevPageLink = this.find('a.prev').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        var nextPageLink = this.find('a.next').css('visibility', 'hidden');

                        // Show appropriate next / prev page links
                        if (this.displayedPage > 0)
                            prevPageLink.css('visibility', 'visible');

                        var lastPage = this.getNumPages() - 1;
                        if (this.displayedPage < lastPage)
                            nextPageLink.css('visibility', 'visible');

                        this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                    }
                });

                /**************** Event handlers for custom next / prev page links **********************/

                gallery.find('a.prev').click(function (e) {
                    gallery.previousPage();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                gallery.find('a.next').click(function (e) {
                    gallery.nextPage();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                /****************************************************************************************/

                /**** Functions to support integration of galleriffic with the jquery.history plugin ****/

                // PageLoad function
                // This function is called when:
                // 1. after calling $.historyInit();
                // 2. after calling $.historyLoad();
                // 3. after pushing "Go Back" button of a browser
                function pageload(hash) {
                    // alert("pageload: " + hash);
                    // hash doesn't contain the first # character.
                    if (hash) {
                        $.galleriffic.gotoImage(hash);
                    } else {
                        gallery.gotoIndex(0);
                    }
                }

                // Initialize history plugin.
                // The callback is called at once by present location.hash. 
                $.historyInit(pageload, "advanced.html");

                // set onlick event for buttons using the jQuery 1.3 live method
                $("a[rel='history']").live('click', function (e) {
                    if (e.button != 0) return true;

                    var hash = this.href;
                    hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

                    // moves to a new page. 
                    // pageload is called at once. 
                    // hash don't contain "#", "?"
                    $.historyLoad(hash);

                    return false;
                });

                /****************************************************************************************/
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div id="page">
            <div id="container">
                <h1><a href="index.htm">Galleriffic</a></h1>
                <h2>Alternate layout using custom previous/next page controls</h2>

                <!-- Start Advanced Gallery Html Containers -->             
                <div class="navigation-container">
                    <div id="Div1" class="navigation">
                        <a class="pageLink prev" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#" title="Previous Page"></a>

                        <ul class="thumbs noscript">
                         <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterGallery" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="thumb" name="leaf" href='<%# "uploads/" & Container.DataItem("photo_file_name")%>' title='<%# Container.DataItem("photo_title")%>'>
                                    <img src='<%# "uploads/" & Container.DataItem("photo_thumbnail_file_name")%>'  alt="Title #0" />
                                </a>
                                    <div class="caption">
                                    <div class="image-title"><%# Container.DataItem("photo_title")%></div>
                                    <div class="image-desc"><%# Container.DataItem("photo_desc")%></div>
                                    <div class="download">
                                        <a href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015_b.jpg">Download Original</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>

                        </ul>
                        <a class="pageLink next" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#" title="Next Page"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="slideshow-container">
                        <div id="Div2" class="controls"></div>
                        <div id="Div3" class="loader"></div>
                        <div id="Div4" class="slideshow"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Div5" class="caption-container">
                        <div class="photo-index"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Gallery Html Containers -->
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what could be causing this? any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the message I understand that can not find the jQuery file

Check this line

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

make sure that the jquery file exist and load into.